# IntentService with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-intentservice

I want to re-start my IntentService (which handles HTTP POST request) every 10 seconds. I tried using AlarmManager and PendingIntent as descrribed in every posts. But my IntentService doesn't starts. I'm unable to find any reason for this so any help would be appreciated.

```
IntentService

public class MyService extends IntentService{

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      System.out.println("Service Started");
        // POST request code here
    }
}

MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime", 5000);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,  0,  intent, 0);
            long trigger = System.currentTimeMillis() + (5*1000);
            AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeM. Yes I registered like `<service android:name=".MyService" />'

Comment: @MikeM. No android:minSdkVersion="11"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();

        TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                MyService.class));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 10000);
        }
```

This will execute at an interval of 10 seconds

Also,add your Service class to manifest:

```
       <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
```

Comment: Where I add this Runnable? In my start() method?

Comment: When do u call the start() method??

Comment: I called it in onCreate

Comment: Then you can either write this code inside `onCreate()` or inside your `start()` method.

Comment: I tried both in start() method and in onCreate but it still not working. If the IntentService starts it will display a Toast. But no Toast showing.

Comment: Yes I added Service in Manifest just like you told.

Comment: Try debugging and check whether Service class start method is getting invoked

Comment: Yes. LogCat displays the System.out message. But it doesn't repeat in every 10 sec which means the Service is not getting started again.

Comment: Where did you write this code?onCreate or your method?

Comment: I created a start() method in onCreate `private void start() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MyService.class));
            }
        };

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
 } `

Comment: Try writing it directly inside onCreate

Comment: Nope. Same result. LogCat output: SVC-Destroying service: com.example.alarmmanager.MyService@41d56728
threadid=13: exiting
threadid=13: bye

Comment: Any other way to restart my intentservice even if the app is not opened?

Comment: See the updated code.This will surely work.Add it inside your onCreate() not in start()

Comment: You are amazing Jas. Its working. The service is getting started again now.

Comment: I think its working even after I've closed the app. Really u r genius man!

Comment: It's a Service class.Always works in background :D Do upvote also